# How to access ISA device in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, pci, isa

I have an ISA device which I want to use under Windows 10. It was working in Windows XP but now the customer wants to upgrade their hardware and Windows. I found this motherboard ([MS-98A9](http://ipc.msi.com/product/pages/ipc/MS-98A9.html)) which features a legacy ISA slot.

In the device manager I see `PCI standard ISA bridge` device loaded under `System device`. But I can't find the ISA device I connected to the ISA slot.

Apparently this is because ISA devices are not plug-and-playable, am I correct?

How can I make my ISA device accessible to Windows 10? Do I need to provide custom INF files/drivers?

Comment: It would definitely help if you supply more information regarding the ISA device. What type of device is it, and what make and model is it?

Comment: It is a custom ISA device our company manufactured back then. It's basically an I/O device.

Comment: As ISA devices usually use fixed I/O (port) or memory ranges, I am 99% sure you need to write a custom device driver which reserves those ranges, and does the low-level communication (because they won't be accessible from user space). So "Windows 10 write custom device driver" is the first thing I'd google...

Comment: http://arstech.com/install/ecom-prodshow/usb2isar.html    How about this adapter?